# Makefile for building an R package linked to an analysis

Tags: r, makefile

Suppose I have a project for which I have developed an R package. The hierarchy might look something like this.

```
/project
---Makefile
---workflow.R
---test.R
---/mypackage
    ---DESCRIPTION
    ---NAMESPACE
    ---/R
        ---func1.R
        ---func2.R
```

`workflow.R` depends on the latest version of `mypackage` being installed. However, I only want to re-build the package if any file inside of it has been modified.

Currently, in my Makefile, I have:

```
PACKAGE=$(wildcard mypackage/**/*)

all: install test workflow

install: $(PACKAGE)
    R CMD INSTALL mypackage

workflow: install
    Rscript workflow.R

test: install
    Rscript test.R
```

However, this will re-install the package every time I run `make test`, even if nothing inside the package has changed. Is there a clean way to avoid this?

Comment: To clarify, the issue is that, unlike compilation, which results in binaries, building an R package returns no output, meaning there isn't really a target for make to look for. One option I've considered is artificially making a target, such as a file with a timestamp of the last package build, but I feel like there has to be a better way...

Comment: What's the content of `$(mypackage)`?

Comment: R function definitions and data. Here's [more info](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) on the general structure from Hadley Wickham. It's definitely a single-purpose package, not meant for CRAN or anything, but rather as a convenient way to organize the analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `install` rule does not create a file named `install` in the current directory, so make tries to remake it each time. This looks like it should be a `.PHONY` target, but that itself won't fix the issue as it will still execute the recipes.

One solution is to have another rule that creates a stub file:

```
.PHONY: all install test workflow

all: install test workflow

install: install.done
install.done: $(PACKAGE)
    R CMD INSTALL mypackage
    touch $@
```

Or you could just make `install` the stub file itself and make it a non-`.PHONY` rule.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to treat the installation as an intermediate step. You can do this by adding

```
.INTERMEDIATE: install
```

to your makefile.

The make manual explains ([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html)):

> If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won’t bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.